# Generating random X,Y coordinates in a grid

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, random

I'm fairly new to Python and this site. I'm hoping someone can help me with this and clarify a few things. I'm stuck at this part in my battleship program. I have a 10x10 grid and I want to randomize the locations for each of the 3 ships within my grid . I also want to display the location when I want them revealed. I've been trying to imitate this using other methods but to no avail.

My current grid looks like this:

```
print(" 0 ","1 ","2 ","3 ","4 ","5 ","6 ","7 ","8 ","9","10")

symbol = " O "
row = 0

for i in range(0,11):
    print(symbol*11 + " " + str(row))
    row += 1
```

For example, I want the grid to look like this when I choose to reveal the location of ships 1, 2 and 3:

```
O O O X O O O O O O
O O O X O O O O X O
O O O X O O O O X O
O O O X O O O O X O
O O O O O O O O X O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O X X X X O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have a look at `random.randint` and `random.randrange`

Comment: I recommend using a Matrix (two dimensional list) for this. @Pynchia has already mentioned random.randint, it is very easy to use. You could generate random numbers according to the indexes / size of your matrix for this.

Comment: BTW, if you count from zero, which is the best way, exclude 10, otherwise you end up with 11 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing too much manual work. You can store the entire grid as an array, and modify the grid, and then print the grid. Also, you don't need to specify 0 in range. Anyway, check this out.

```
grid = [['O' for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)] # use generators to create list

def print_grid():
    print("  " + " ".join(str(i) for i in range(10))) # " ".join() puts the " " between each string in the list
    for y in range(10): 
        print(str(y) + " " + " ".join(grid[y]))

print_grid()

# OUTPUT:
#   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# 0 O O O O O O O O O O
# 1 O O O O O O O O O O
# 2 O O O O O O O O O O
# 3 O O O O O O O O O O
# 4 O O O O O O O O O O
# 5 O O O O O O O O O O
# 6 O O O O O O O O O O
# 7 O O O O O O O O O O
# 8 O O O O O O O O O O
# 9 O O O O O O O O O O

grid[0][3] = 'X'
grid[1][3] = 'X'
grid[2][3] = 'X'
grid[3][3] = 'X'

print_grid()

# OUTPUT:
#   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# 0 O O O X O O O O O O
# 1 O O O X O O O O O O
# 2 O O O X O O O O O O
# 3 O O O X O O O O O O
# 4 O O O O O O O O O O
# 5 O O O O O O O O O O
# 6 O O O O O O O O O O
# 7 O O O O O O O O O O
# 8 O O O O O O O O O O
# 9 O O O O O O O O O O
```

Hopefully that's most of what you need!

EDIT: Did not see the randomize aspect, my apologies!

Use random.randint, for example (but move the import to the top of your file):

```
import random
x = random.randint(1, 8)
y = random.randint(1, 8)

if random.randint(0, 1): # flip coin to determine orientation
    grid[y-1][x] = 'X'
    grid[y][x] = 'X'
    grid[y+1][x] = 'X'
else:
    grid[y][x-1] = 'X'
    grid[y][x] = 'X'
    grid[y][x+1] = 'X'
```

To check for collision, you might rather than setting those 3 as X off the bat, verify that they are all O first, and if not, reroll the position and orientation.

Comment: the OP says the grid is 10x10, so you can exclude 10 form the count

Comment: Your answer will be downvoted, since it DOES NOT answer the question. Use comments instead. There are separate premises for code-review. I was tempted as well, I must admit. Since you have gone that far, you might just add the solution and show how to use `randrange` / `randint`

Comment: Hm, the OP seems to explicitly do 0-10 inclusive in his code, which was what I built off of. Also, edited with randint.

Comment: upvoted! True, in fact I believe his code is wrong, whereas his description (and sample printout) is correct